# geom_polygon + map projection = inexplicably cut into two shapes?

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I'm trying to draw a world map in Winkel Tripel projection, using ggplot2; it will ultimately have some data on top of it.  Natively, as far as I know, ggplot can't do Winkel Tripel, so I have kludged around this with manual projections.  I've got everything except the ocean layer, which doesn't come out right.  Code:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
    library(ggplot2)
    library(sp)
    library(rworldmap)
    library(rgdal)
})
ll.to.wt <- function (points)
    as.data.frame(spTransform(SpatialPoints(points, CRS("+proj=longlat")),
                              CRS("+proj=wintri")))

world <- fortify(spTransform(getMap(), CRS("+proj=wintri")))
xlimits <- ll.to.wt(matrix(c(-180,180,0,0), nrow=2))$coords.x1
ylimits <- ll.to.wt(matrix(c(0,0,-60,85), nrow=2))$coords.x2
lseq = seq(-60, 85, by=.25)
boundary <- ll.to.wt(data.frame(
    long = c(rep(-180, length(lseq)), rep(180, length(lseq)), -180),
    lat  = c(lseq,                    rev(lseq),          lseq[1])))

ggplot() +
    geom_polygon(data=boundary, aes(x=long, y=lat), fill="#9AC5E3") +
    geom_map(data=world, map=world, aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
             color="#888888", fill="#f2caae", size=0.25) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits=xlimits, expand=c(0,0)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits=ylimits, expand=c(0,0)) +
    coord_equal() +
    theme(
        axis.line=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        legend.justification = c(0,0), # bottom of box
        legend.position      = c(0,0), # bottom of picture
        panel.background=element_blank(),
        panel.border=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
        panel.margin=unit(0, "lines"),
        plot.background=element_blank())
```

Rendered:

[image: world map drawn correctly except that the blue ocean fill only covers the "end caps" of the map, not the region in the middle]

You can see that what was meant to be a single polygon fill has been chopped into two separate polygons, and they only cover the "end caps" of the map, not the middle.  How do I make it fill under the entire map?  I presume that the problem is with the definition of "boundary", but I don't see anything in the [`geom_polygon`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_polygon.html) documentation to explain what might be wrong.

Comment: I think this might be a bowtie polygon, ie ll, ul, lr, ur, ll rather than a proper path around ll, ul, ur, lr, ll where these stand for upper/lower, left right. Can't test myself right now

Comment: @mdsumner That's why the lseq is reversed the second time.

Comment: ok sorry, btw it's the scale_y_continuous step, probably that breaks the polygons in a problematic way - you can see it's fine (but for the y extent) by commenting that line out

Comment: @mdsumner I tried that before posting, and it didn't change a thing.  Weird.  I might play with it some more after this paper is done :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ever since `ggalt` you can do those PROJ.4-based projections directly:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sp)
library(rworldmap)
library(rgdal)
library(ggalt)
library(ggthemes)

world <- fortify(getMap())
world <- subset(world, id != "Antarctica")
lseq = seq(-60, 85, by=.25)
boundary <- data.frame(
    long = c(rep(-180, length(lseq)), rep(180, length(lseq)), -180),
    lat  = c(lseq,                    rev(lseq),          lseq[1]))

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_polygon(data=boundary, aes(x=long, y=lat), fill="#9AC5E3")
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=world, map=world, 
                    aes(long, lat, map_id=id),
                    color="#888888", fill="#f2caae", size=0.25)
gg <- gg + coord_proj("+proj=wintri")
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg
```

[image]

The real problem with your original is your polygon limits since you're nicking the top of Antarctica with your boundary box:

```
lseq = seq(-53, 85, by=.25)
boundary <- data.frame(
    long = c(rep(-180, length(lseq)), rep(180, length(lseq)), -180),
    lat  = c(lseq,                    rev(lseq),          lseq[1]))

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_polygon(data=boundary, aes(x=long, y=lat), fill="#9AC5E3")
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=world, map=world, 
                    aes(long, lat, map_id=id),
                    color="#888888", fill="#f2caae", size=0.25)
gg <- gg + coord_proj("+proj=wintri")
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg
```

[image]

Though it would have been fine with `coord_proj()` anyway:

```
gg + coord_proj("+proj=wintri", ylim=c(-60, 85))
```

[image]

So, just tweak those a bit:

```
lseq = seq(-53, 85, by=.25)
boundary <- data.frame(
    long = c(rep(-180, length(lseq)), rep(180, length(lseq)), -180),
    lat  = c(lseq,                    rev(lseq),          lseq[1]))

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_polygon(data=boundary, aes(x=long, y=lat), fill="#9AC5E3")
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=world, map=world, 
                    aes(long, lat, map_id=id),
                    color="#888888", fill="#f2caae", size=0.25)
gg <- gg + coord_proj("+proj=wintri")
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg
```

[image]

and it works fine without intercoursing the penguins directly:

```
gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_polygon(data=boundary, aes(x=long, y=lat), fill="#9AC5E3")
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=world, map=world, 
                    aes(long, lat, map_id=id),
                    color="#888888", fill="#f2caae", size=0.25)
gg <- gg + coord_proj("+proj=wintri", ylim=c(-53, 85))
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect the subset + not using scale_y_limit is the real fix here

Comment: Updated with more info/examples (super bad head cold going on, so I was too brief last night…apologies).

Answer (score 0):

While using 'ggalt' is the "right answer", here's a way to get what you wanted - by cropping out Antarctica first (though I don't support this, it's really bad), and using 'scale_y_discrete'. I'm not au fait enough with the gg-verse to know why, but I gather the continuous croppping breaks off the southern boundary and somehow draws the paths around the two halves again. Discrete cropping probably picks the "nearest" coords and so keeps the southern boundary.

We really need better tools to cross the sp/ggplot2 divide, and while we have a zoo of partial fixes for local problems there's no proper unification of the two. 'ggalt' is one of the better ones.

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
library(ggplot2)
library(sp)
library(rworldmap)
library(rgdal)
})
ll.to.wt <- function (points)
as.data.frame(spTransform(SpatialPoints(points, CRS("+proj=longlat")),
                        CRS("+proj=wintri")))

## not much of a "world" without Antarctica . . 
badworld <- subset(spTransform(getMap(), CRS("+proj=wintri")), 
               !NAME == "Antarctica")
world <- fortify(badworld)
xlimits <- ll.to.wt(matrix(c(-180,180,0,0), nrow=2))$coords.x1
ylimits <- ll.to.wt(matrix(c(0,0,-60,85), nrow=2))$coords.x2
lseq = seq(-60, 85, by=.25)
boundary <- ll.to.wt(data.frame(
long = c(rep(-180, length(lseq)), rep(180, length(lseq)), -180),
 lat  = c(lseq,                    rev(lseq),          lseq[1])))

ggplot() +
geom_polygon(data=boundary, aes(x=long, y=lat), fill="#9AC5E3") + 
 geom_map(data=world, map=world, aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
       color="#888888", fill="#f2caae", size=0.25) +
scale_x_continuous(limits=xlimits, expand=c(0,0)) +
scale_y_discrete(limits=ylimits, expand=c(0,0)) +
coord_equal() +
theme(
axis.line=element_blank(),
axis.text.x=element_blank(),
axis.text.y=element_blank(),
axis.ticks=element_blank(),
axis.title.x=element_blank(),
axis.title.y=element_blank(),
legend.justification = c(0,0), # bottom of box
legend.position      = c(0,0), # bottom of picture
panel.background=element_blank(),
panel.border=element_blank(),
panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
panel.margin=unit(0, "lines"),
plot.background=element_blank())
```